# How to parse e-mail bounce notifications

Tags: email, smtp

What options do I have to parse the e-mails that have bounced? I am receiving the bounce notification from e-mail servers but don't know what to do with it.

Thanks

Edit: I just want to know how to do it. If I receive 30k bounces per day, how can I remove the e-mails from my newsletter?

Comment: Do you want some sort of parse script? Are you getting an error you don't understand? If latter, edit to include example.

Comment: really depends on the MTA.  What are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you have problems. Bounce messages have no standard format (except perhaps some).

If you control the list, I suggest setting a Errors-To header and/or the explicit Return-To header. If you can afford the cost of queuing each message individually, then using VERP [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) addressing is a huge win and should mostly solve your problem.

To fully understand the implications of setting these headers I suggest reading the details from a site like Wikipedia.

Comment: Indeed.  VERPs are how several industrial-strength mailing list softwares handle the problem.  However, this is entirely the province of the envelope, not the headers.  Recommending using headers is wrong.  `Errors-To:` was a **UUCP** mail mechanism, doesn't work in general, and has been deprecated for almost a decade and a half, now.

Comment: A deprecated a header doesn't mean that it is useless, but it is perhaps not as useful as it might have been. Useful and perhaps venerable software like GNU mailman still include this header.

Comment: Tripe.  It most definitely **does** mean that it is useless in this case.  Only three MTS softwares out of the many in use in the world have ever even recognized it.  In the first, its functionality has been disabled as standard since V8.8, released in the mid-1990s.  In the second, the functionality was outright _removed_ seven years ago.  In the third, it has never actually been used in the part of the MTS that generates bounce messages, which uses the envelope _as everyone else does and as the standards dictate_.